# What is the easiest way to add cities and countries of the world to an HTML5 form?

Tags: html, forms

I'm creating a form, and I would like to allow the user to choose their country, and their city. What is the most effective way to do it?

Comment: Good question. Even I have this, but I generally go with asking people write their place names.

Comment: I think your question requires a bit more information. Is this strictly HTML? Or are you considering querying a database for the data and then just displaying the dropdowns in html? Do you want to list literally every country/state/province/city ever? Or just a select (large) amount?

Comment: What does "effective" mean? If you mean a good UX, consider asking in [ux.stackexchange.com](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @LogicaLInsanity Sorry, I forgot to mention it, I might consider querying a database for the data and then display the dropdowns in html, but I'm looking for the most effective way to do it, that wouldn't take much time, I'd preferably list every country/state/city , when the user selects a country, I will only show them the states/cities.. in their country

Answer (score 4):

For things like state and country, the possible number is reasonably small enough that you can build dropdowns for this without too much hassle. [Here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Country-Selecter-with-Flags-flagstrap.html) is a plugin for `jQuery` that has a "country picker" pre-made, and you can easily find the same for State on Google.

When you start talking about cities, there are a vastly large number of them. In my opinion, you're far better off using a simple `textbox` for this and letting the user fill it in themselves.

**EDIT**
Here is an example of building a country list from a database in `MVC`:

**Country class (Model)**

```
//This class represents a Country
public class Country
{
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public string CountryName {get; set; }

    public Country(int countryID, string countryName)
    {
        this.CountryID = countryID;
        this.CountryName = countryName;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
List<Country> countries = new List<Country>(); //Create a list of Country objects
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> countryList; //List to hold the values for the dropdownlist
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString); //build a connection with your connection string

connection.Open();
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("SELECT CountryID, CountryName FROM Country", connection); //query the table
query.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

SqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader(); //execute the query

while (reader.Read()) //read out the results, set each result to a Country object
{
    Country country = new Country(
        Convert.ToInt32(reader["CountryID"]),
        reader["CountryName"].ToString());

        countries.Add(country); //add to the initial list
}
connection.Close();

//build the list of <SelectListItem>s to pass to the view
countryList = countries.Select(c => new System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem
{
      Text = c.CountryName,
      Value = c.CountryID.ToString()
});

ViewBag.CountryList = countryList; //add the list to ViewBag
```

**And the View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryList, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "formItem" })
```

This code hits your database for the list of countries and builds a `List<Country>` from the `SqlDataReader`. Then we turn these results into a `List<SelectListItem>` to pass into the view.

The result is a dropdown list that will always contain whatever records are in your database. If you add/remove items, the list will be representative of this.

The `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID)` binds the selected `Value` to the model's `ID` property, so you simply select this value on `POST`. (Note that your model will need to contain an `ID` property for this to work!

**EDIT** to emphasize the "fun" of making a city selector:

I really, *really* advise against trying to build a city selector. Check out the [list of cities in Kansas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Kansas) (something I picked at random). I didn't bother to count these, but this is a pretty big list, and that alone is *one state* in *one country* in the world.

If you went with a database, you'd easily have thousands of records for the United States alone, and that only leaves you with 195 other countries to build data for.

Perhaps you can find a repository that already has this information available, but the amount of work required to make this happen seems prohibitive.

Comment: Is Kansas a country? `:P` I don't even know that!

Comment: @PraveenKumar No, but it does represent (roughly) 1/50th of a country, which even further illustrates my point :P

Comment: Could you possibly add a code-snippet?

Comment: @Matt Although the question isn't tagged with `MVC`, I have added what I feel is the easiest way to build a dropdownlist of countries to a form.

Comment: That looks good, thank you! +1